# Google test testing C code, no destructor warning

Tags: c++, c, testing, googletest

I'm currently testing my `C` code with google test which works fine. I fake my `C` code with the `fff.h` framework.

The problem is not the tests them self but the compiler warnings I get when I compile them, I get warnings for each test:

```
class 'theTest_specificTest_Test' defines a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator but does not define a destructor, a move constructor or a move assignment operator [cppcoreguidelines-special-member-functions]
```

My test class looks like this:

```
DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;
FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(int, a_func, const char *, const char *);
...
class theTest : public testing::Test
{
public:
   // some variables here
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
        RESET_FAKE(a_func);
        FFF_RESET_HISTORY();
    }

    virtual void TearDown()
    {
    }
};
```

A test looks like this:

```
TEST_F(theTest, theThest_specificTest)
{
    a_func_fake.return_val = 1;  
    int ret = some_func();
    ASSERT_EQ(ret, 0);
}
```

Comment: [Do not use underscores in test names](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#why-should-test-suite-names-and-test-names-not-contain-underscore) especially when suite name is so similar to test name. This can lead to unexpected errors (this might be an explanation of your problem).

Comment: The problem seemed to not be with my code but with google test itself, https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/2639. I did however follow your advice to not have problems in the future.